# Amazon HTTP API gateway not working via VPC Link

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have `Fargate ECS` task which is under `ALB` and everything is working fine.
Since this `ALB` is internal, I want to expose it via the new `HTTP API Gateway` via `VPC` link for `HTTP API`.

I have created the new `VPC` link for `HTTP API` (specifying the security group and subnets for the internal `ALB`), and created `HTTP API Gateway` and connected it to the `VPC` link + `ALB`.

I am trying to map specific routes (and `{proxy+}` as well in other cases), but it seems that I am getting,

```
{
  "message": "Service Unavailable"
}
```

on the correct links.

(On the non existing `URLs`, I get `404` - as expected).
I tried this also with internet facing `ALB` (connecting it via `VPC` link as well - for testing purposes only), but it seems this is again the case.

I even tested it with `NLB` with `HTTP API VPC` link - and still same behavior.

Any idea if this even works? (Since it is in the `UI`, I assume it does?)

**UPDATE**:
It seems that it works only in `default` stage For other stages, I have created (dev and beta) for which I get `404`.

To me, it seems that since the `URLs` for dev and beta are `/dev` and `/beta`, the load balancer is 'getting confused'.

Comment: Have you found solution for this issue. I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 17):

VPC Link requires to be in a private subnet (most likely because of NAT Gateways). If you place it in public subnets, it will result in 503 errors, which might be your case as well.

Comment: As Tailor888 says, your VPC link must be in private subnets. Otherwise, it might respond well the first couple of requests, but will start to fail with a 503 code around the 3rd one.

Comment: i don't get how this crucial piece of information is not in the AWS docs. seriously.

Comment: Making VPC link in private subnets solved the 503 issue. Thank you @Tailor888

Answer (score 1):

HTTP APIs don't perform URL mapping like the original REST APIs. API Gateway just passes the path what it gets in curl/invoke for HTTP APIs -

If you pass `/foo` in the URL the backend should have a resource `/foo`

If you pass `/foo/bar` in the URL the backend should have a resource `/foo/bar`

For the older VPC Links you could use the URL to map

```
/foo -> /bar/baz
```

That could be the reason for the 404s.

As for the `503 Service unavailable`, take a look at the access logs of the ALB and see if any connections from API Gateway are received. It's likely the request is being routed to the default instead of any custom ALB rules you may have defined. This will lead your request to an incorrect target group causing 503s if the targets are not healthy or missing.

Comment: just posted an update, it seems to work for the default stage. But it does not work for other stages (like dev,beta). It probably can't map /dev/health to the /health URL on the Application Load Balancer

Answer (score -1):

You found 404, so clients reach YourAPI.It may be just nginx settings.

Client <---"https" and fqdn---> API Gateway  <--- "http" and fqdn ---> YourAPI

nginx on my environment below,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com;
}
```